# How do I iterate through several left joins LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

When I try to loop through this SQL to LINQ method, I only recieve all the rows of forum_category. What I really want it to do, is to get all rows from forum_category and also return all the forums that matches the category id, here's the expected outcome:

```
FORUM_CATEGORY (categoryid, categorytitle)
 - FORUM (forumid, forumtitle, forumdescrition) -> (latest topic => topicid, topictitle) -> (latest post on that latest topic => postid, postadded, username) -> total topic count, total post count in this forum only
 - FORUM (forumid, forumtitle, forumdescrition) -> (latest topic => topicid, topictitle) -> (latest post on that latest topic => postid, postadded, username) -> total topic count, total post count in this forum only
 - FORUM (forumid, forumtitle, forumdescrition) -> (latest topic => topicid, topictitle) -> (latest post on that latest topic => postid, postadded, username) -> total topic count, total post count in this forum only

FORUM_CATEGORY
 - FORUM [...]
 - FORUM [...]
 - FORUM [...]
```

You get the idea...

-

Here's what I currently get:

```
FORUM_CATEGORY
 - FORUM (forumid, forumtitle, forumdescrition) -> (latest topic => topicid, topictitle) -> (latest post on that latest topic => postid, postadded, username) -> total topic count, total post count in this forum only

FORUM_CATEGORY
 - FORUM (forumid, forumtitle, forumdescrition) -> (latest topic => topicid, topictitle) -> (latest post on that latest topic => postid, postadded, username) -> total topic count, total post count in this forum only
```

That is, only one forum for each forum category.
Here's the LINQ code:

```
var forum = (from c in context.forum_category
             join f in context.forum on c.id equals f.categoryid
             join t in context.forum_topic on f.id equals t.forumid
             join tc in context.forum_topic on f.id equals tc.forumid into tcount
             join p in context.forum_posts on t.id equals p.topicid
             join pc in context.forum_posts on t.id equals pc.topicid into pcount
             join u in context.users on p.userid equals u.id
             orderby p.added descending
             select new ForumIndexModel
                        {
                            CategoryId = c.id,
                            CategoryTitle = c.title,

                            ForumId = f.id,
                            ForumTitle = f.title,
                            ForumDescription = f.description,
                            TopicId = t.id,
                            TopicTitle = t.title,

                            PostId = p.id,
                            PostAdded = p.added,

                            Username = u.username,

                            TopicCount = tcount.Count(),
                            PostCount = pcount.Count()
                        }).ToList();
return View(forum);
```

This is just one example of some of the different approaches I did.

EDIT: clarified what I want more specifically.

Comment: You want an outcome with a (1) PostId and a PostCount, TopicCount? Can a Post belong to multiple Topics?

Comment: A post cannot belong to multiple topics, why would it?

Comment: I don't know. Why do you have a class with PostId and TopicCount ?

Comment: Your ForumIndexModel class only has one forum per category. Shouldn't you have a List<Forum_Id>, List<Forum_title>, or better yet use a Forum class and use List<Forum> ?   Something doesn't look right

Comment: DisplacedGuy, that is exactly what I'm trying to do. How would I set those lists when selecting a new ForumIndexModel?

Comment: Okay, I added another answer because it is a completely different approach, the one that I prefer.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add another answer by request of the original poster. I'm using **Entity Framework** and have **defined associations** that are used in my example.  My data model (for purposes of this example) are three tables because there is a many to many relationship but yours would be simpler having only the category and forum tables for the one to many relationship (plus addtl. look up tables)

**So my data model (physical)**

- lm_m_category
- lm_m_category_link  (this is many-to-many table)
- lm_m_link

I have defined associations in EF ( **nCat**, **nLink** for navigating to Category or Link from the xref table ).  EF handles the joins for you this way.

So the code to load this isn't one statement but you asked me to show you how I would do it using EF.  I didn't put examples of the Category and Link classes they are simple id, desc classes but Category has a list of Links.  My physical data model uses the lm_m_* tables.

```
List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();

Category newCategory;
Link newLink;

foreach (var category in db.lm_m_category_link.Include("nCategory").Include("nLink").ToList())
    {
    newCategory = new Category();

    newCategory.category_id = category.category_id;
    newCategory.category_name = category.nCategory.nCat.category_name;

    foreach (var link in (IEnumerable<lm_m_link>)category.nLink)
    {
        newLink = new Link();

        newLink.link_id = link.link_id;
        newLink.link_name = link.link_title;
        newLink.link_url = link.link_url;

        // add link to list
        newCategory.category_links.Add(newLink);
    }

    // add category 
    Categories.Add(newCategory);
}
```

Comment: While this is not the exact correct answer I was looking for, this helped me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I though your sort was causing problem but after further review...

I've got another thought, your **ForumIndexClass looks wrong** for what you want. Shouldn't your ForumIndexModel have **Lists** (or IEnumerable) **on Forum columns**?  You are assigning single values where there should be lists.  Your class should look more like...

```
  class ForumIndexModel
    {
    int CategoryId {get; set;}
    string CategoryTitle {get; set;}

    List<int> ForumIds {get; set;}
    List<string> ForumTitles {get; set;}
    List<string> ForumDescriptions {get; set;}

    ... you get the idea...

    }
```

To select into lists do something like this:

```
public class C
{
  A TheA {get;set;}
  List<B> TheBs {get;set;}
}


//g is an IEnumerable<B> with a key property of A

List theResult =
(
  from a in ListA
  join b in ListB on a.ValueAB = b.ValueAB into g
  select new C()
 {
    TheA = g.Key,
    TheBs = g.ToList()
  }
).ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting the correct data, and changing my sort doesn't make any difference. However, I can only loop through my forum-data once, on each category which loops correctly.

Comment: Exactly. How would I assign those lists via LINQ when I'm selecting into ForumIndexModel?

Comment: okay, so it seems you are looping through the ForumIndexModel after the select... which means my second answer here is probably wrong too, my bad for not getting clarification.

Comment: I usually use Entity Framework and don't know how to assign list in one statement using Linq, if it is even possible. I'd like to see the SQL that linq generated for that query because it looks like your query is okay.

Comment: I'm also using Entity Framework. But if I can't do it in one statement, how can I do it otherwise?

Comment: I added something to my answer... as I said I'm not a Linq expert but I found an example of how you can select to lists.

Comment: I already tried what you suggested, but not entirely. I will get back to you soon. Meanwhile, here's my generated SQL http://pastebin.com/fh1CP8kf